# Why the second value is null when I tried to pass two value through intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried to pass two values from one activity to another through Intent,so here is what I did:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SetAlarm.this,Show.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("t",things);
bundle.putString("pa",picturePath);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And then I tried to get all these values in the target Activity,so I wrote these code below:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String s= extras.getString("t");
String path = extras.getString("pa");
```

The first value is fine,but the funny part is that the path is null. So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: have you check picturePath value before pass to intent ?

Comment: what is "picturePath" ?

Comment: yes,I even made a toast to check that.picturePath is just a String value

Comment: please checl picturePath is String Value

Comment: @Vincent,if picturePath is not null then your code is perfect for get picturePath value.

Comment: i m with @HareshChhelana

Comment: Have you tried just using an intent extra just in case? I've had this happen to me before and just used multiple intent extras. Give it a try and see if it's still null. Use Intent extras = getIntent(); and String s = extras.getStringExtra("t"); String path = extras.getStringExtra("pa");

Comment: just use edited text .